# PHP call variables

Tags: php, arrays, call

I want to call variable from another PHP page. Example:

I have PHP page called **index.php**,  and there is an array like:

```
<$php

$arr = array("banana","apple","orange");

$>
```

I've created one another PHP page: home.php  and I want to call array ($arr) from         **index.php**  to  **home.php**.

How can i do this?

Comment: Requests for [tutoring](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help6) are usually off-topic. Primary site intent is coding approaches, not readymade [code](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help5), nor tutorials per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to assume that `index.php` and `home.php` are different pages and you `can not` include one in the other

Then you can use session :

`index.php`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['array'] = array("banana","apple","orange");
```

`home.php`

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['array']);
```

Comment: So, the same session is in index.php and home.php? Right?

Comment: Yes just use the session key to access it ... see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php on php Sessions

Comment: I'm actually JAVA programmer :) Can i do this with php class and functions. I can post my code if you want?

Comment: You can put it in paste bin .. let me that a look at it

Comment: Should I paste my code in my question? Or I can it upload on the web. I have my own domain :)

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Paste Name/Title: For Baba. I didn't paste my css,picutre and delete.php

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/mhCumd13 :)

Comment: `<?php  session_start(); ?>` should always be on top of the page ant not in the middle

Comment: <?php session_start();?> is on the top of page? :)

Comment: Maybe you think: on the top of <html> ???

Comment: `<?php  session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>` at the first line .. tested your script it works .... but i think should should consider storing information in a database because session do expire

Comment: Yes i know, i try to add contacts in list and than to delete some contacts by clicking on delete.png. I use this also for one-many relation in mysql database. We can have one user that have more contacts. And the user can insert more contacts by one click

Comment: I need to remove selected contact from my list and when I com back to index.php from delete.php. There is just one contact, if i had two.

Comment: Yes, the same session is in both pages, but not the same array !? When I remove one item in delete.php page it should be removed from another...

Comment: With `unset($_SESSION['array']['key_u_want_to_delete']` you can do that ....

Comment: Yes, i try with unset to do this in delete.php. But how can I check if i deleted one contact from my array. I use Mozilla. When I go to "Go back on page, Right click or pull down to show history" i get an error like: "This document is no longer available."

Comment: Here is one solution: http://pastebin.com/un9Z3zru But it is still in the array.

Comment: It should be http://pastebin.com/XJKxAUmz

Comment: YES, YOU HAVE RIGHT. IT WORKS. BUT THERE IS A STILL PROBLEM WITH "GO BACK ONE PAGE" to default page ???

Comment: Yes, but with this print_r: rint_r($_SESSION['names']); for checking :)

Comment: I try with <a href="index.php"> Back </a> but when I click on it there is no contact in my array to see. Why?

Comment: Hey mate, are you there? I have solved my problem, this code:  if (!isset($_SESSION['names']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') I have changed with this:  if (!isset($_SESSION['names']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')

Comment: @Aldin Habibović well done .. had to go for lunch

Comment: No problem, i have still the problem with "GO back"

Comment: @Aldin Habibović give me some min be right back

Comment: Sure, I will be here (20:38 PM)

Answer (score 0):

If that is the full content of index.php then you need to include the first page into the second, so in home.php you would have

```
 <?php
      require_once('index.php');
      print_r($arr);
 ?>
```

Keep in mind if you do this that if you require index.php, it will include, and attempt to run all the code from there.  This means if index.php references home.php, and you use the above example you will find yourself in a neverending loop.  If, however, index.php just has the code you put above, this should work fine

Comment: Using `require_once` (as you have) should prevent the loop. There are other considerations here, though. `index.php` may have side-effects that are harmful to `home.php` for instance.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but there is a lot of another stuff in index.php. It was just an example.

Comment: Then you should use sessions as mentioned above, or if $arr is a static value, put it in it's own file or make it a constant and include it from a 'header' type file.

Answer (score 0):

You either use `$_SESSION` `require` or `include`

**home.php**

```
<?php

include 'index.php';

print_r($array);

?>
```

or

```
<?php

require('index.php');
// you can also use require_once to prevent looping

print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: See first answer. "Yes, I understand, but there is a lot of another stuff in index.php. It was just an example"